# How to configure Laravel 5.2.41 in Production Server(Redhat 7 with Apache and Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have installed Laravel 5.2.41 in Production Server and also create a virtual host and map the Document root path to the public_html folder. Project folder is inside the laravel folder like /public_html/laravel. When I hit the url its showing me 500 internal server error. Please help me to give a solution.

Comment: Map document route to the public folder within the laravel project folder

Comment: I also tried that but the result is same

Comment: Then you need to read your error logs - it could be any number of issues from incorrect permissions, wrong database credentials etc. Without ssh access to the server (not actually suggesting you give these out btw!!) no one on here can really help with such limited information

Comment: I suppose $response = $kernel->handle( $request =lluminate\Http\Request::capture()); this portion is not working from index.php page, because when I tried to print the response object its not showing me anything. But upto before that line the index page is echoing something if I write.

Comment: @Steve my folder permission is set as 775 and all the files permission set as 664. Is those permission are correct?

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/testdev.com/public_html' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/testdev.com/public_html/index.php

Answer (score 0):

So its probably a lack of permission for your apache user on your project files. Check with command:

> ll -a

if your user (apache user) have permissions and the correct level of permission for your project folders.

Most folders should be normal "755" and files, "644".

Also, you may check if your apache mod_rewrite is on.